# Android makefile: How can I use LOCAL_CFLAGS values in if/else statements?

Tags: android, makefile

I want to make a conditional makefile where some source files are exluded from the build depending on LOCAL_CFLAGS values. Any ways I can do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried: LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \

file1.cpp

ifneq (, $(findstring _MY_VALUE,$(LOCAL_CFLAGS)))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
file2.cpp
endif

Comment: Drop the space after the comma in the `ifneq` and that should work correctly for when `_MY_VALUE` is in `LOCAL_CFLAGS`. I'm assuming it always evaluates to true at the moment.

Comment: It now works. It seems like I had a typo somewhere.